# Create list with all unique possible combination based on condition in dataframe in Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dictionary, combinations

I have the following dataset:

```
d = {
'Company':['A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B','C','C','C','C','D','D','D','D'],
'Individual': [1,2,3,4,1,5,6,7,1,8,9,10,10,11,12,13]
}
```

Now, I need to create a list in Python of all pairs of elements of 'Company', that correspond to the values in 'Individual'.

E.g. The output for above should be as follows for the dataset above:
((A,B),(A,C),(B,C),(C,D)).The **first three tuples, since Individual 1 is affiliated with A,B and C** and the **last one since, Individual 10 is affiliated with C and D**.

*Further Explanation* -
If individual =1, the above dataset has 'A','B' and 'C' values. Now, I want to create all unique combination of these three values (tuple), therefore it should create a list with the tuples (A,B),(A,C) and (B,C). The next is Individual=2. Here is only has the value 'A' therefore there is no tuple to append to the list. For next individuals there's only one corresponding company each, hence no further pairs. The only other tuple that has to be added is for Individual=10, since it has values 'C' and 'D' - and should therefore add the tuple (C,D) to the list.

Comment: can you clarify "All combinations of 'Company' if Individual=1"

Comment: yes of course. If individual =1, the above dataset only has 'A' and 'B' values. Now, I want to create all unique combination of these two values (tuple), therefore it should create a list with the tuple (A,B). The next is Individual=2. Here is only has the value 'A' therefore there is no tuple to append to the list. Next its Individual '3', which has the company values 'A' and 'C'. Therefore it should add (A,C) to the list. Etc.

Comment: @JanOhlenbusch, I've added a separate answer for the refined question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution to your refined question:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from itertools import combinations

data = {'Company':['A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B','C','C','C','C','D','D','D','D'],
        'Individual': [1,2,3,4,1,5,6,7,1,8,9,10,10,11,12,13]}

d = defaultdict(set)

for i, j in zip(data['Individual'], data['Company']):
    d[i].add(j)

res = {k: sorted(map(sorted, combinations(v, 2))) for k, v in d.items()}

# {1: [['A', 'B'], ['A', 'C'], ['B', 'C']],
#  2: [],
#  3: [],
#  4: [],
#  5: [],
#  6: [],
#  7: [],
#  8: [],
#  9: [],
#  10: [['C', 'D']],
#  11: [],
#  12: [],
#  13: []}
```

Answer (score 4):

One solution is to use `pandas`:

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'Company':['A','A','A','B','B','B','C','C','C'],'Individual': [1,2,3,1,4,5,3,6,7]}

df = pd.DataFrame(d).groupby('Individual')['Company'].apply(list).reset_index()
companies = df.loc[df['Company'].map(len)>1, 'Company'].tolist()

# [['A', 'B'], ['A', 'C']]
```

This isn't the most efficient way, but it may be intuitive.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is already close to what I am looking for - I think I was not clear enough on the output - since your solution gives you n-tuples for each individual. I need all dual(2)-tuple combinations of each individual and add them to the list. (I need to create an edge-list that can be processed in networkX based on the affiliation). I believe that there is a way in the itertools module, with the combination iterator - however I am still stuck..

Comment: @JanOhlenbusch, can you give representative example data (input & output) to cover your new requirements?

Comment: Thanks, I updated the question. I already found a possible solution to this, as an extension to your part (see below). Not sure if it is the cleanest or most efficient solution though. We have a final dataset of 1-2 million entries, unsure if RAM will be sufficient.

`import itertools as it`
`edgeList = []`
`for x in companies: 
    pairs = list(it.combinations(x, 2))
    edgeList.extend(pairs)`

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
temp=df[df.duplicated(subset=['Individual'],keep=False)]
print temp.groupby(['Individual'])['Company'].unique()

>>>1    [A, B]
>>>3    [A, C]
```